# Laravel Passport - Custom column names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

So I'm trying to modify the default Passport migrations to use different column names than what it ships with. I want to use "id_User" instead of "user_id" and "id_Client" instead of "client_id."

My only question is, will this mess anything up later down the line? Is Laravel passport expecting a user_id column, and is there a way to change the default behavior to use id_User instead?

Comment: have you tried looking at you database/migration/<create_passport_table> folder? you can define it there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would probably mess things up down the line. If you do a [search](https://github.com/laravel/passport/search?q=client_id&type=Code) for `client_id` in the Passport repository you'll get a few results. And a [search](https://github.com/laravel/passport/search?q=user_id&type=Code) for `user_id` reveals many results.

It might depend how you would use Passport in your application, but I would not recommend changing the column names, especially not `user_id`. Perhaps have a look through the methods you plan to use in [Passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport) and see how it would affect you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your User model.

```
public function getId_UserAttribute(){
   return $this->user_id;
}
```

This way you don't mess with the core functionality but you still get your attributes the way you want it when you work with them.